# there is no speed-up using multi-gpus

Tags: python, performance, theano

I try to test the performance of multi-gpus using the following code:

```
test__multi.py

import time
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import shared
from theano import function

a = time.time()

v_00 = shared(
        value=random((10240, 10240)).astype(theano.config.floatX, copy=False)
        ,target='dev0'
)
v_01 = shared(
        value=random((10240, 10240)).astype(theano.config.floatX, copy=False)
        ,target='dev0'
)
v_10 = shared(
        value=random((10240, 10240)).astype(theano.config.floatX, copy=False)
        ,target='dev1'
)
v_11 = shared(
        value=random((10240, 10240)).astype(theano.config.floatX, copy=False)
        ,target='dev1'
)
b = time.time()
print b - a

f = function(inputs=[], outputs=[
        theano.tensor.dot(v_00, v_01),
        theano.tensor.dot(v_10, v_11)
        ]
)
c = time.time()
print c - b

res0, res1 = f()
d = time.time()
print d - c
```

I got results as the attached picture showed, there is no improvment when I used two different gpu device.(THEANO_FLAGS='contexts=dev0->cuda0;dev1->cuda1')

The log in the terminal is as follows:

```
lanlin@UbuntuGpu:~$ cd python
lanlin@UbuntuGpu:~/python$ THEANO_FLAGS='contexts=dev0->cuda0;dev1->cuda0' python test__multi.py
Mapped name dev0 to device cuda0: Tesla K80 (CuDNN not available)
Mapped name dev1 to device cuda0: Tesla K80 (CuDNN not available)
6.47632694244
0.34957909584
2.27110910416
lanlin@UbuntuGpu:~/python$ THEANO_FLAGS='contexts=dev0->cuda0;dev1->cuda1' python test__multi.py
Mapped name dev0 to device cuda0: Tesla K80 (CuDNN not available)
Mapped name dev1 to device cuda1: Tesla K80 (CuDNN not available)
6.49380016327
0.36678981781
2.40865397453
```

Answer (score 0):

A few changes will reveal the improvement:

1. Tell the function outputs to stay on the GPU using e.g. `theano.tensor.dot(v_00, v_01).transfer('dev0')`.
2. Call the function once before timing (it will compile), then many times in a loop while timing, and drop the sizes from 10,240 back down to 1,024.
3. Only take the final answer off the GPU e.g. `np.asarray(res0)` or maybe even `print(res_0)` after the loop is complete, and time when this is done.  This ensures all the computations are actually done.

What you have to avoid to observe the speedup is transferring the output to the CPU every time the math is executed.  The time elapsed from the start of the loop to the end of the `np.assarray` call will be the total time to compute and to transfer the last answer.  The time elapsed during the loop will only be the time to queue up the operations in the GPU, but not to complete them.  I'm not sure how to time the GPU execution time in isolation; you have to infer it.